# Should I fit(X_train, y_train) or fit(X,y) when using pipeline with gridsearchCV and cross_validate? (python)

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to make a pipeline that will do the following things: preprocessing, train one model (e.g. random forest), use GridSearchCV to tune hyperparameters (using nested cross validation to prevent data leak), and use cross_val_score to assess the performance of the model.

When I look online I'm finding that some people do fit(X,y) whereas other people do fit(X_train, y_train). I've included an example of each below (I appreciate that the first example has more preprocessing but I don't think that makes a difference here).

I'm confused on this. Why does one version use all the data whilst the other version only uses the training set? I presumed you always used the training set.

Does the decision just hinge on whether youre using cross_validate (or cross_val_score) or not? As in, if I do cross_validate (or cross_val_score) at the end I should use fit(X, y) and if I don't use cross_validate I should use fit(X_train, y_train)?

(I'm looking to use the 1st code example, so if there's anything else obviously wrong with it please do let me know)

Example that uses fit(X,y):

```
#Organise data
X = df.drop('target', axis= 1)
y = df['target']
continuous_var = ['X1', 'X2', 'X3']
cat_var = ['X4', 'X5', 'X6']

#Preprocessing pipe
con= Pipeline([('scale', MinMaxScaler()),('missing', KNNImputer())])
cat = Pipeline([('encoding', OrdinalEncoder())])

pipe = ColumnTransformer([("cont_features", con, continuous_var), ("categorical_features", cat, cat_var)])

pipe_rf= Pipeline([('cleaning', pipe), ('clf', RandomForestClassifier())])

param_range = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
grid_params_rf = [{'clf__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
        'clf__min_samples_leaf': param_range,
        'clf__max_depth': param_range,
        'clf__min_samples_split': param_range[1:]}]

gs_rf = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe_rf,
            param_grid=grid_params_rf,
            scoring='accuracy',
            cv=10, 
            n_jobs=jobs)
gs_rf.fit(X, y)  ############# <- note here

results = cross_validate(gs_lr, X, y, scoring=['accuracy', 'precision'], cv=5, 
            n_jobs = -1, return_train_score = True)   ############ <- note here


#Getting output
gs_rf.best_estimator
gs_rf.best_score_
pd.DataFrame(results).mean()
```

Example with fit(X_train, y_train):

````
#Organising data
X = df.drop('target', axis= 1)
y = df['target']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 0)


pipe_rf = Pipeline([('scl', StandardScaler()),
            ('clf', RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42))])

param_range = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

grid_params_rf = [{'clf__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
        'clf__min_samples_leaf': param_range,
        'clf__max_depth': param_range,
        'clf__min_samples_split': param_range[1:]}]

gs_rf = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe_rf,
            param_grid=grid_params_rf,
            scoring='accuracy',
            cv=10, 
            n_jobs=jobs)

gs_rf.fit(X_train, y_train)  ############ <- note here

#Getting output
gs_rf.best_estimator
gs_rf.best_score_
y_pred = gs.predict(X_test)

```
````